# Cleaner method for mass-declaring lists?

Tags: r, list

I have an iterative process that involves appending modified/utilised data to sublists of lists. It feels quite messy to declare a bunch of lists e.g. `testList <- list()` x 12, so that within the loop I can jump straight into the below code:

```
testList <- list()
otherTestList <- list()
anotherTestList <- list()

for(i in 1:10){
  testList[[i]] <- testData
  otherTestList[[i]] <- otherTestData
  anotherTestList[[i]] <- anotherTestData
}
```

The above code would require declaration of 3 lists at the start of the code, which wouldn't be so much of an issue, but I have around 12 lists so their mass declaration makes the code quite ugly. I was wondering if there was a solution to this problem? Something I'd considered was somewhere along the lines of using lapply to create the lists in one line, but this doesn't appear to be an option due to the need to declare the objects as some type prior to using them as lists.

Comment: mistake on my part, but it was just something arbitrary to represent the loop - thanks for pointing it out though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `assign()`. Say you have the names of your lists or want to set them iteratively:

```
for (i in 1:5){
  assign(paste0("x",i),list())
}
```

If you have the names:

```
listnames = c("testList", "otherTestList","anotherTestList", ...)
    for (i in 1:5){
      assign(listnames[i],list())
    }
```

This will give you 5 variables named `x1`, `x2` or `testList`, `otherTestList`... containing an empty list each.